# How to use webpack and ES6 with dependencies using a CommonJS module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, lodash, commonjs

I am working on a project with laravel that uses (as it is the default) webpack to bundle its assets. In there, I do have a dependency on a package that in turn has dependencies to lodash and deepdash.

Since deepdash is provided as a mixin for lodash, the usage of it is (as per the docs) like this:

```
// load Lodash if you need it
const _ = require('lodash');
//mixin all the methods into Lodash object
require('deepdash')(_);
```

or, if you want to use ES6 syntax (at least that is my understanding), it would translate to:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import deepdash from 'deepdash';

deepdash(_);
```

Having done that, I am trying to use webpack to create a bundle now to be used in the browser. My problem is, that for some reason it appears that webpack replaces the import of lodash with some "__webpack_require__" magic functionality, which leads to lodash not being a function anymore, and the browser says this:
[image]

To better demonstrate my problem I created a demo github repo with just trying to webpack deepdash and lodash: [ArSn/webpack-deepdash](https://github.com/ArSn/webpack-deepdash) Here is the line that the browser complains about: https://github.com/ArSn/webpack-deepdash/blob/master/dist/main.js#L17219

I have played around a lot with adding babel configuration en mass and it felt like my best shot was the plugin [babel-plugin-transform-commonjs-es2015-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-commonjs-es2015-modules). I tried that, the result was still exactly the same.

I feel like either I have a deep misunderstanding of the situation or I am missing just one tiny little thing. I can however for the life of me not figure out which one it is and what.

Side notes:

- I know there is also a ES6-Version of deepdash, and apparently when using both of those the webpack mechanics work fine (as is stated in the response to the [github issue I opened](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/issues/36) over at deepdash for this), but the dependency I am using is not using those. Also, I do not really see (or understand?) the point of having a dedicated ES6 version there in the first place.
- The very same code (using deepdash this way with lodash) works just fine when executed on node.js, where it is not bundled with webpack before, obiously. I should mention it is using the require-syntax here though.

Comment: `import * as deepdash from 'deepdash';` but I've seen some bundlers convert the glob to an object, even if `module.exports` was a function.

Comment: leads to almost(!) exactly the same error, only the `(...)` before the "is not a function" does not show now

Comment: What version are you using?  I am having the same issue on a boilerplate with "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"

Comment: In the example repo (which reproduces the problem) I am using webpack 4.40.2 and webpack-cli 3.3.9 - should both be pretty up-to-date. I did not find an reported issue on the webpack project yet, but maybe I just missed it (or are the first to find it)

Comment: I just upgraded to webpack 4.41.0 - so the must current one - but it yields exactly the same

Comment: The matter is that deepdash is not exported in the bundle :`/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
var deepdash=function(){"use strict"; ..............);
//# sourceMappingURL=deepdash.min.js.map


/***/ })`

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what would be the solution here? Answer from madflow below seems pretty neat (and working, yay!) right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointing explicitly to the deepdash main module works for me when running one of the examples from the deepdash website:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import deepdash from 'deepdash/deepdash';

deepdash(_);
```

Webpack [uses](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4674) the `browser` entry as default:

```
  "main": "deepdash.js",
  "module": "es/standalone.js",
  "browser": "browser/deepdash.min.js",
```

This will not work for Webpack and static imports - because there is nothing really "exported".

Also: Commonly these entries do not point to minified builds. These are usually only for CDN use cases and not for bundlers.

On the contrary `'deepdash/deepdash.js'` exports the decorator function.

The `deepdash-es` build basically does the same thing except that it uses es6 exports. Maybe this is the way that treeshaking can work out of the box. Not sure about at that...

In order to circumvent the "browser" issue - the author of deepdash could just simply amend it to use "deepdash.js" or remove it:

https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

> If your module is pure javascript and can run in both client and server environments, then you do not need a browser field.

Comment: This works like a charm! Can you elaborate why this is necessary, or even better, say what deepdash would have to change so they don't break the current interface but also it would work in the "standard way" `import deepdash from 'deepdash'`? Maintainer of deepdash seems to be very open to changes to make this work, so I'd love to open a pull request at deepdash, I will accept your answer in any case of course

Comment: I updated my answer. It was interesting to read up on this.  I am not an really an expert when it comes to the internals of bundling.

Comment: You ended evenings of me trying to figure this out and miserably failing, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. Do you have the same nick in Github? Just wanted to add you to contributors list

Comment: I for one have the same handle in Github.